# El Capitan TextEdit bug: renaming file on desktop moves the file's icon

Tags: macos, osx-el-capitan, textedit

I upgraded my OSX from 10.8.6 to El Capitan (10.11.5) and since then I’m having this bug:

modify and save a text file located on Desktop using TextEdit app --> Sometimes the file icon is moved to a different position on the desktop. 
(file name “test.rtf” first changes to “test.rtf.****” and then back to “test.rtf”. It looks like file modification causes a temporary file to be created and then renamed.

[image]

This seems to be due to a [TextEdit bug](http://www.macworld.com/article/2038430/bugs-and-fixes-when-textedit-won-t-save.html). Sometimes TextEdit writes [temporary files](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/is-it-possible-to-stop-textedit-from-saving-versions.1464574/) when saving.

Is there a solution?

Comment: When you say you "upgraded" I can't see how this was from 10.8 to 10.11 without upgrading to at least 10.10 first.  Was this a clean install?  F2 is a Windows convention, not Apple.  I suggest you take a look at your keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: I upgraded from Mountain Lion to El Capitain by downloading an update from iTunes.

Comment: Do a clean install, meaning *wipe HD and install from scratch*.

Comment: I think this is a TextEdit bug

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to rename the selected file/folder - Press Return (or Enter).
   This is valid to desktops or any other finder window.
   F2 is for Windows OS.
2. Not sure what are you trying to do here. Please elaborate?